# Does Jira Kanban offer measurement reports?

Tags: agile, kanban, jira

What are the gadgets, reports or metrics available in Jira Kanban that are useful for management reporting and to measure team performance?

Is there a way to get throughput, cycletime and lead time from Jira?

Answer (score 2):

Jira offers a [series of very useful reports](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/reporting-939938675.html) for different purposes. Reports in Cloud and Server instances of Jira are mainly the same, as far as I could see.

For **Jira Kanban** specifically, there are two specific reports (details obtained from the source links):

### [Cumulative Flow Diagram](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/cumulative-flow-diagram-777002689.html):

A Cumulative Flow Diagram (CFD) is an area chart that shows the various statuses of work items for an application, version, or sprint. The horizontal x-axis in a CFD indicates time, and the vertical y-axis indicates cards (issues). Each colored area of the chart equates to a workflow status (i.e. a column on your board).

The CFD can be useful for identifying bottlenecks. If your chart contains an area that is widening vertically over time, the column that equates to the widening area will generally be a bottleneck.

[image: Cumulative Flow Diagram example]

### [Control Chart](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/control-chart-777002660.html)

The Control Chart shows the Cycle Time (or Lead Time) for your product, version, or sprint. It takes the time spent by each issue in a particular status (or statuses), and maps it over a specified period of time. The average, rolling average, and standard deviation for this data are shown.

A Control Chart helps you identify whether data from the current sprint can be used to determine future performance. The less variance in the cycle time of an issue, the higher the confidence in using the mean (or median) as an indication of future performance.

[image: Control Chart example]

Answer (score 0):

The standard reports in Jira provide a good start. In practice though, quite often it is not enough and depending on the level of maturity and desire to truly improve your Kanban system you could look into additional apps like https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218809/quantify-kanban-metrics that makes throughput, cycle time and lead time really easy to use.